# Hakaras HaTov in Halachah

Tags: halacha-theory, halacha

Hakaras HaTov (Gratitude) is a very important trait in Torah. Can the principle of Hakaras HaTov create a situation where what is otherwise prohibited becomes permitted?

Comment: I think one of the words "forbidden" and "prohibited" is not what you meant.

Comment: Short answer, yes, but I can't remember the exact midrash which gives a nice example.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it is prohibited to use flattery or to lie to somebody.

However, there is a case in the gemorah (Sanhedrin 107b and Sotah 47a) where out of hakarot hatov for a fine meal and a good lodging, the rav says to the innkeeper that she is beautiful. His student objects that her eyes are not pretty, to which the rav pushes away his student.

Comment: According to Rashi in Sotah, this is incorrect. The Rabbi was complimenting her actions, not her appearance.

Comment: @Barry did the innkeeper know he was doing this when he said it?

Comment: @Barry, Yes, but wouldn't something like that still be *g'neivas da'as* in general?

Comment: The text doesn't say the Rabbi was addressing the innkeeper - it's more likely he was complimenting her to his student in a private conversation. Furthermore, the Rabbi genuinely meant what he said. No lying or misleading going on here.